# What language should i use for dynamic client side and server side form validation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I am very confused about so many languages available.I want to do dynamic form validation  and well as after pressing submit button validation as i am learning.

**javascript** can do client side dynamic validation with functions like **onblur** for 
example when i entered wrong email format it can through me error like wrong email format
but if i enter right email format it has to check on the sever side for the existence of email just like **onblur** did for client side validation.

i am not sure what language to learn for this when i am considering the compatibility for
browsers in the future as well.

I am thinking of learning `ajax,php,html,mysql`.
please suggest what else would be required or better.

Comment: your question is very confused

Comment: HTML5 might help with simple validations on client side. JavaScript may help with complex validations on client side. On server - php or javascript (node.js) is only that might help.

Comment: On the browser side, you are limited to JavaScript. Start without AJAX first (this is a data format not a programming language) as it is rather complicated for beginners. On the server side, you can use anything you like. PHP is fine, as is Ruby, Python, Dot Net, Perl, Java (and many more). Bear in mind that discursive questions of this kind are off-topic, as there is no "right" answer - see the Help section.

Comment: Please try to avoid typos to avoid getting downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest option for me, is to learn PHP for server-side validation.

If you want to add client-side validation (which is not a "MUST", but is a "PLUS"), you can use Javascript. Avoid using Ajax, jQuery or any kind of advanced libraries and functionalities until you get a basic understanding of what happens where.

Comment: `learn PHP for server-side validation.` Don't learn a language just for validation. Learn PHP as a whole if you have to serve pages by it, or any other server side language for that matter.

Comment: but when we need to pass variables from php and javascript for dynamic form validation like onlbur in javascript.I start looking for options like ajax..-:)

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky Rephrase: Learn PHP and use it for server-side validation, among hundreds of other obvious things

Comment: @munish Yes, when you want to validate things on the fly, you move on to Ajax. But as with many comments, try to learn how to do it without Ajax first. Ajax is only really necessary if you are trying to see if a username exists, for example.